# Collapsing toolbar with a button but the button should move as the toolbar text moves in Android

Tags: android

As you can see in the video.

http://sendvid.com/xydqzql4

The text "Knowledgeable boys" and edit button is moving along.

I wanna make something like that.

i have already used the collapsible toolbar layout in my XML and the collapsible text is moving as expected, but i don't know how to add a button on its right so that it would move as the text moves.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try this example code.....https://github.com/saulmm/CoordinatorBehaviorExample

Comment: thanks brother for the code :)

Comment: it is useful for you?

Comment: i need to see the code and find my thing of interest as i just want to have the button and text stick together while moving

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried to replicate the profile animation of `Hangouts` 4.0to show how a `CoordinatorLayout.Behavior` could be used Sample code on [github](https://github.com/saulmm/CoordinatorBehaviorExample)